# EXCEL - Do chart with data range varying

Tags: excel, graph, charts

Im trying to do an excel chart where the data will vary depending on the results, I'm been reading many articules online for this topic, however, I didnt manage to accomplish it on my data so far.

Here is my problem:

I have 3 lines which I need to update each one based on daily results (game results): so far, there are some games concluded and other that didnt even start yet, therefore, I only want to include on my graph, those games which already happened:

[image]

Therefore, I have one cell on sheet that gives the line of the last game available `L34`, so, I just want include the first game until the last one:

[image]

My last game updated is on line 37 and my formulas to y axis text and data are:

I have a formula `="COMPARAÇÃO!"&S39&":"&T39` on cell `V39` which means `COMPARAÇÃO!E7:F37` for the y axis text and the formula `="COMPARAÇÃO!"&S40&":"&T40` on cell `V40` which means `COMPARAÇÃO!G7:G37` for the data

I created two cells name (tag): one for the y axis `text_range` where I used the formula `=INDIRECT(COMPA!$V$39)`and another one for the line data `data_range` with the following data `=INDIRECT(COMPA!$V$40)`

[image]

So finally I tried to change the graph series data as following (`BOLAO` is the name of the excel file and `COMPA` is the excel sheet with all the data):
[image]

However, I get the following error: (It was found a problem with one or more references of formula in the file)

[image]

I dont know what can be wrong with my file

Comment: try doing =COUNTA(data_range) and =COUNTA(text_range) in a cell and see if those formulas return the expected value or the error you showed above.

Comment: I tried and returned only 1, that is strange, I dont know what can be wrong

Comment: I found out the issue, it was very siily, I havd changed the name of the sheet and I was still putting the old name, it hasd worked perfectly now, thank you

Comment: Glad it helped. Helps me with these dynamic named ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing `=COUNTA(data_range)` and `=COUNTA(text_range)` in a cell and see if those formulas return the expected value or the error you showed above. – John F Jun 25 at 2:40

Comment: Thank you, it has helped to figure out my mistake which was the name of the sheet, everything is working fine